# Django Rest Framework XML - Create multiple objects with a different xml name field compared to the Django Model

Tags: python, xml, django, django-rest-framework

I'm sending to Django (1.6.11) Rest Framework (3.0.5) an XML file (I don't have control over the file) with the below information.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Company xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Invoices>
    <Invoice>
      <Id />
      <Number>150</Number>
      <Date>2012-11-20</Date>
      <InvoiceItems>
        <Item>
          <Sku>MAT</Sku>
          <Description>Example description</Description>
          <Total>10</Total>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <Sku>RMS</Sku>
          <Description>Example description 2</Description>
          <Total>10</Total>
        </Item>
      </InvoiceItems>
      <Carriage>
        <Sku />
        <UnitPrice>20</UnitPrice>
      </Carriage>
      <ItemsTotal>50</ItemsTotal>
    </Invoice>
  </Invoices>
</Company>
```

How can I iterate through these items (Invoices>Invoice>InvoiceItems>Items>) and save each object (Item) linked to its Invoice model ?

```
models.py

class Invoice(models.Model):

    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=10)
    invoice_date = models.DateTimeField()
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    items = models.ForeignKey('Item', blank=True, null=True, related_name='items')
    carriage = models.ForeignKey('Carriage', blank=True, null=True, related_name='carriage')

class Item(models.Model):

    item_sku = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    item_description = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)
    item_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)

class Carriage(models.Model):

    carriage_sku = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    carriage_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)

views.py

@api_view(['POST'])
@parser_classes((XMLParser,))
def zynk_upload(request, format=None):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.data      
        serializer = InvoiceSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

serializer.py

class InvoiceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = ('id', 'invoice_date', 'total', 'carriage','items')

    def to_internal_value(self, data):

        id = data['Invoices']['Invoice']['Number']
        invoice_date = data['Invoices']['Invoice']['Date']
        total = data['Invoices']['Invoice']['ItemsTotal']
        carriage_sku = data['Invoices']['Invoice']['Carriage']['Sku']
        carriage_price = data['Invoices']['Invoice']['Carriage']['UnitPrice']
        item_sku = data['Invoices']['Invoice']['InvoiceItems']['Item']['Sku']
        item_description = data['Invoices']['Invoice']['InvoiceItems']['Item']['Description']
        item_total = data['Invoices']['Invoice']['InvoiceItems']['Item']['Total']

        return {
            'id': id,
            'invoice_date': invoice_date,
            'total': total,
            'carriage': {
                        'carriage_sku': carriage_sku,
                        'carriage_price': carriage_price,
                    },
            'items': {
                        'item_sku':item_sku,
                        'item_description': item_description, 
                        'item_total': item_total,                      
                    },
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):        
        carriage_data = validated_data.pop('carriage')
        carriage_id = Carriage.objects.create(**carriage_data)
        items_data = validated_data.pop('items')
        items_id = Item.objects.create(**items_data)
        return Invoice.objects.create(carriage=carriage_id, items=items_id,**validated_data)
```

Comment: what is your solution for this?
I also need this :D

Answer (score 1):

If a field name is different, I believe you can specify the mapped-to/from name through class-scoped variables:

```
class InvoiceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    my_xml_name = serializers.CharField(source='my_django_name')
    [...]
    class Meta:
        [...]
        fields = ([...], 'my_xml_name')
```

[More documentation on explict field names can be found here.](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-fields-explicitly)